# Stack Apps "Welcome Back" banner text isn't centered

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, design

This appear to be specific to Stack Apps. The text is centered on every other site I've tried. See below:

[image: It's not even aligned to the left of normal content...]

Compared to how it should appear:

[image: Nice and centered, how cool does that look!?]

Comment: Previously reported: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/114181/stackapps-notification-bar-is-off-centered